# Deleting data in firebase 7

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I came across a problem, I am making a function where you can get rid of chats in my app so I have this function

```
function deleteconvo() {
        const me = firebase?.auth?.currentUser?.uid;
        const members = [me, recipient.uid];
        firebase.db.collection("conversations").remove({ members }); 
    }
```

Firebase is telling me that:

> firebase.db.collection("conversations").remove({ members });  is not a function

I also tried .delete and I cant find any answers online. Anyone have a solution to this?

*note: I understand that I have to grab the docs value too, because I am in the conversation collection of the the database each conversation has its own unique ID, which I dont know how to grab and store that in a variable.*

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the [official Firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#node.js) regarding how to delete data.

In that page you can find examples in different languages on how to delete documents, fields and collections.

For example to delete an entire collection or subcollection in Cloud Firestore you need to retrieve all the documents within the collection or subcollection and delete them.

And to delete a document you can use the `delete()` method:

```
const res = await db.collection('cities').doc('DC').delete();
```

`